# What does this vector notation mean

Tags: notation, vectors

I was reading through the paper "Deformation Constraints in a Mass-Spring Model to Describe Rigid Cloth Behavior" and came across some vector notation that I am not familiar with. The notation in question is boxed in blue:

[image: here]

Initially I though that this meant the length between particle $P_{ij}$ and particle $P_{kl}$, but it is clearly a vector and not a scalar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vector $\vec{AB}$ is $B-A$.

$|\vec{AB}|$ is the distance between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Just to expound a bit more: it’s the vector that points from $P_{i,j}$ to $P_{k,l}$ $\ddot\smile$